# Use of undeclared type 'T' Xcode 9

Tags: swift

I have this error since I have updated to Xcode 9:

> Use of undeclared type 'T'

```
func addDistance(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, latitudeKey: String = "lat", longitudeKey: String = "lng") -> [T] {

    return self.map { (obj) -> T in

        // Calculate distance
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: obj.value(forKeyPath: latitudeKey) as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: obj.value(forKeyPath: longitudeKey) as! CLLocationDegrees)
        let center = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)
        let distance = location.distance(from: center)

        // Save
        obj.objDist = distance

        return obj

    }

}
```

Comment: So what's `T` then? I don't see a declaration for it, and neither does the compiler.

Comment: Thank you all the problem was solved.

Comment: @DarioMartinNeira how did you solve it? You should create an answer and select it as solved

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to declare your addDistance function as a generic:

```
func addDistance<T>(center: ....)
```

Also, since you are using obj.value(...) in the closure, there has to be some requirement for type T such as being an NSObject or some other protocol with a value() function.

This means that the generic declaration of addDistance must also specify this contraint for T.

For example:

```
func addDistance<T:NSObject>(center: ....)
```

[EDIT]

Upon further consideration, since you're using self.map, your addDistance function is probably part of a collection type.

You are returning elements of your collection:

The self.map's closure : (obj) -> T ..., returns obj so the type of T is the same as obj which will be of type Element (within the collection)

Given this, T is the same type as the collection's Element and you could simply replace T with Element without making the function a generic.